# replace view pager fragment with another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

So I am building an Android application which utilize view pager code. The first view of the view pager is a list where user can choose one and view more detail regarding items of which the user selected. I have managed to successfully do this using fragment inside fragment method.

My current issue is with the third view of the view pager. the third view show a summary of action that has been done in the first view and then user can click a button which will replace the current third view with another fragment. The code I used is identical with the one i used in the first view, which is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_fragment_layout, container, false);
    btn_1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    btn_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                CF = new CustomFragment();
                ft.addToBackStack("fragment_a");
                ft.add(R.id.fragment_custom_container, CF, "custom_fragment1");
                ft.commit();
                fm.executePendingTransactions();
                }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

The onCreateView code for the container of the fragment is as follow:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     try{
       rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_container, container, false);
       fm = getFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
       CF = new CustomFragment();
       Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
       ft.addToBackStack("somewords");
       ft.add(R.id.fragment_custom_container, CF, "custom_fragment");
       CF.setRetainInstance(true);
       ft.commit();
       fm.executePendingTransactions();
     }
     catch(Exception E)
     {
       E.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("exception:"+E.getMessage());
     }
    return rootView;
}
```

Whereas the xml layout file of the container is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/ll_fragment_custom_layout"
android:background="#fff">
        <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_custom_container"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

However the code did not work and I received exception:

```
05-07 12:29:54.570: E/AndroidRuntime(7365): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060045 (com.example.fragmentname:id/fragment_cart_container) for fragment fragmenta{42bae2a0 #0 id=0x7f060045 fragment b}
```

Is there any error that I made?

Comment: your error is that you didn't return proper view inside your Fragmenta.check onCreateView() function of your Fragment.but in your code i can't find problem,maybe full codes related to your fragments helps.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project ?

Comment: @Arash I have updated the code with the whole oncreateview as you have suggested

Comment: @GrlsHu I already tried cleaning the project. But the problem still remains.